# What Visual Studio for .NET 1.0 web development?

Tags: visual-studio, .net-1.0

I have a old web application developed in .NET 1.0. How can I do some minor changes in it? What Visual Studio do I need and how do I obtain it? Or can I develop in some other tool?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It was called [VisualStudio.NET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fx6bk1f4%28VS.71%29.aspx), followed by Visual Studio 2003 (also known as version 7.1).

I don't think this is available anymore, unless you have a pro MSDN subscription or above.

Visual Studio 2005/2008/2010 cannot be used for this, nor can mono-develop, but you might be able to use the version of [SharpDevelop](http://www.icsharpcode.net/opensource/sd/download/) that supports 1.1.

Comment: This is not accurate, 7.1 was VS2003, targeting .NET 1.1

Answer (score 3):

You'd need Visual Studio 2002, it targeted .NET 1.0.  That edition didn't last long, Visual Studio 2003 and .NET 1.1 quickly followed.  Your project should have good odds opening and running properly on that edition.  Odds get lower once you move to VS 2005/8 and .NET 2.0+

If you don't have VS2002 then you can obtain a license through an MSDN Library subscription.  An auction site like Ebay is a cheaper alternative.

Answer (score 1):

It was originally called **Visual Studio.NET** but later on also got referred to as **Visual Studio 2002**.

I looked it up and apparently you can still download it if you have an MSDN subscription.

Answer (score 0):

You can use VS 2005, VS 2003, or VS 2002.  I think the 2002 edition was called VS.NET.

From http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/06/20/vs-2008-multi-targeting-support.aspx

> What about .NET 1.0 and 1.1?
>
> Unfortunately the VS 2008 multi-targeting support only works with .NET 2.0, .NET 3.0 and .NET 3.5 - and not against older versions of the framework.  The reason for this is that there were significant CLR engine changes between .NET 1.x and 2.x that make debugging very difficult to support.  In the end the costing of the work to support that was so large and impacted so many parts of Visual Studio that we weren't able to add 1.1 support in this release.
>
> VS 2008 does run side-by-side, though, with VS 2005, VS 2003, and VS 2002.  So it is definitely possible to continue targeting .NET 1.1 projects using VS 2003 on the same machine as VS 2008.

Comment: Note however that Visual studio 2002/2003 isn't supported on Windows Vista or 7 (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/aa948853.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Take a back up of your project. 
Try to down load visual studio express 2008 version and open the project. you will have an option to convert. Once converted download the latest visual studio express and then convert into the latest version.

BTW Visual stuido express is FREE

Note:
Some of the methods may not be supported or droped. you need to recode them or replace them.